# How can I increment my <p> tag when I clicked add in my HTML table?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

This is my whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Pre-Enrollment</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/customcss.css">
    </head>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li role="presentatoion" class="active"><a href="FromEnrollment.php">Pre-Enrollment</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="Students.php">Students</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="Subjects.php">Subjects</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <br>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">    <!--RED-->
                <div class="col-md-3" >
                    <form id="idNumber" action="FromEnrollment.php" method="POST">
                    <div class="input-group">
                     <!--   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID NUMBER"> --> 
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <!--<form action="newPhp.php" method="POST">-->
                                <input type="text" placeholder="ID NUMBER" class="form-control" name="input">
                                <input type="submit" value="Enter" name"Enter" class="btn btn-default">
                            <!--</form>-->
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="resetIdNumber()" value="reset">Reset</button>     
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">
                    <select style="width: 120px;">
                        <option value="All">Overall Term</option>
                        <option value="First">First Term</option>
                        <option value="Second">Second Term</option>
                        <option value="Short">Short Term</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Apply</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="reset">Reset</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row" >

                <?php

                 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

                    if( isset($_POST['input']) ){
                    include 'dbcon.php';

                        $Idnumber = ($_POST['input']);
                         $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE id_number = '$Idnumber'");
                         $currentTerm = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM pre_enroll WHERE id_number = '$Idnumber'");


                        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        $result2 = $currentTerm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        // $last_name = print_r($result[0]['last_name']);
                        // $first_name = print_r($result[0]['first_name']);
                        // $course = print_r($result[0]['course']);

                         echo "
                            <div class='col-md-2'>
                                <p>Name:  ";
                                print_r($result[0]['last_name']);
                        echo " ";
                                print_r($result[0]['first_name']);
                         echo"</p>
                            </div>";


                         echo "
                            <div class='col-md-4'>
                                <p>Course and Year:  ";
                                print_r($result[0]['course']);
                        echo"-";
                                print_r($result[0]['year']);
                         echo"</p>
                            </div>";


                       echo "
                            <div class='col-md-4'>
                                <p>Current term:  ";
                                print_r($result2[0]['term']);
                         echo"</p>
                            </div>";


                            // <div class='col-md-4'>
                            //    <p>Current Term: </p>
                            // </div>;

                    }

                  }else{

                    echo "
                     <div class='col-md-2'>
                        <p>Name: </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-md-4'>
                       <p>Course and Year: </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-md-4'>
                       <p>Current Term: </p>
                    </div>";
                  }
                ?>

            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <form id="Subjects" action="#">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="filterData()" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">  
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="resetSubjects()" value="reset">Reset</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <p>Total Units: <b> </b></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>

            <?php
            include 'dbcon.php';
            $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT subjects.coursenumber as 'Course No.', subjects.destitle as 'Descriptive Title', enr_stat.term as 'Term', subjects.units as 'Units' FROM subjects INNER JOIN enr_stat ON subjects.coursenumber = enr_stat.coursenumber");
            ?>

            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col" id="table-wrapper">
                        <div id="table-scroll">
                            <table class="table" id="myTable">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Course No.</th>
                                    <th>Descriptive Title</th>
                                    <th>Term</th>
                                    <th>Unit</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>


                                <?php
                                $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                foreach ($results as $row) {
//                                        echo "<form action=''>";
                                        echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<td>".$row['Course No.']."</td>"; 
                                        echo "<td>".$row['Descriptive Title']."</td>"; 
                                        echo "<td>".$row['Term']."</td>";
                                        echo "<td>".$row['Units']."</td>";
                                        echo "<input type='hidden' name='CourseNo' value='".$row['Course No.']."'/>";
                                        echo "<input type='hidden' name='descrp' value='".$row['Descriptive Title']."'/>";
                                        echo "<input type='hidden' name='term' value='".$row['Term']."'/>";
                                        echo "<input type='hidden' name='units' value='".$row['Units']."'/>";
                                        echo "
                                        <td>
                                            <button class='btn btn-default btn-sm' onclick='addDataToLocalStorage(this)'>
                                                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus' aria-hidden='true'></span>
                                            </button>    
                                        </td>
                                        ";

                                        echo "</tr>";
//                                      echo "</form>"; 
                                }
                                ?>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col" id="table-wrapper">
                        <div id="table-scroll">
                            <table class="table" id="copy">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Course No.</th>
                                    <th>Descriptive Title</th>
                                    <th>Term</th>
                                    <th>Unit</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                           </table>  
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-11">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Apply</button>
            <br>
        </div>
        <script>
            function resetIdNumber(){
                document.getElementById("idNumber").reset();
            }

            function resetSubjects(){
                document.getElementById("Subjects").reset();
            }

            function filterData() {
                var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
                input = document.getElementById("myInput");
                filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
                table = document.getElementById("myTable");
                tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

                for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
                    if (td) {
                        if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                            tr[i].style.display = "";
                        } else {
                            tr[i].style.display = "none";
                        }
                    }       
                }
            }

            function addDataToLocalStorage(r){
                var courseNo = r.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[0].innerText;
                var descriptive = r.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1].innerText;
                var term = r.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[2].innerText;
                var unit = r.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[3].innerText;
                var t = "<button onclick=clearData(this);deleteRow(this); class='btn btn-default btn-sm'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>";
                // alert(courseNo + " " + descriptive + " " + unit);

                var list = {
                    courseNumber: courseNo,
                    descriptiveTitle: descriptive,
                    term: term,
                    units: unit,
                };

                var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(list);
                localStorage.setItem("list" + localStorage.length,jsonObject);

                var thatTable = document.getElementById("copy");
                var newRow = thatTable.insertRow(-1); //at the last position of the table

                var newCell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
                newCell1.innerHTML = courseNo;
                var newCell2 = newRow.insertCell(-1);
                newCell2.innerHTML = descriptive;
                var newCell3 = newRow.insertCell(-1);
                newCell3.innerHTML = term;
                var newCell4 = newRow.insertCell(-1);
                newCell4.innerHTML = unit;
                var newCell5 = newRow.insertCell(-1);
                newCell5.innerHTML = t;
            }

            function clearData(r) {
                var data = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
                var data_key = data - 1;
                localStorage.removeItem(localStorage.key(data_key));
            }

             function deleteRow(r) {
                 var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
                 document.getElementById("copy").deleteRow(i);
            }

            //  function refresh(){
            //     if (localStorage.getItem("list0") != null) {     ///if there is "student1" exist in localStorage
            //          for(i = 0; i <= localStorage.length; i++){
            //             var stores = localStorage.getItem("list" + i);
            //             var jsonString = JSON.parse(stores); //convert text to javascript object

            //               var thatTable = document.getElementById("copy");
            //               var newRow = thatTable.insertRow(-1); //at the last position of the table

            //                 var newCell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
            //                     newCell1.innerHTML = courseNo;
            //                 var newCell2 = newRow.insertCell(-1);
            //                     newCell2.innerHTML = descriptive;
            //                 var newCell3 = newRow.insertCell(-1);
            //                     newCell3.innerHTML = term;
            //                 var newCell4 = newRow.insertCell(-1);
            //                     newCell4.innerHTML = unit;
            //                 var newCell5 = newRow.insertCell(-1);
            //                     newCell5.innerHTML = t;

            //         }
            //     }
            //}
        </script> 
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </body>   
</html>
```

How can I increment my `<p>Total Units:<b> </b></p>` whenever I clicked add button in my table. My table fetched some data in my database and when I clicked add, The data will copy in the next html table. I want every time I clicked the add button, my `<p>` tag will increment by how many units the subject is.

I tried using the `stepUp()` method in js but I dont know how to get the value of the units row in my html table. Is there any way to do it with my current codes?

Comment: set any class name to the column units like this <td class="unit" >2</td>.. each time of button click run the each function like this var total=0; $('.unit').each(function(){  total+=$(this).text(); });  and set class to p tag $('p_tag_class').html('Total Units:' +total+'<b> </b>');

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a span with special ID

```
<p>Total Units:<b><span id="countRow"></span></b></p>
```

Then count your rows, and just

```
document.getElementById("countRow").innerHTML = count
```

Comment: I wanted to just count the value on my 3rd row.

Answer (score 0):

Set any class name to the column units like this

```
<td class="unit" >2</td>
```

Each time of `button click` after  run the `each function` like this

```
var total=0; 
$('.unit').each(function(){ total+=parseInt($(this).text()); });
```

And set any class name to `p` tag

```
$('.p_tag_class').html('Total Units:' +total+'<b> </b>');
```

**Update 1:**

```js
$(document).on('click','[type="button"]',function(){

  $('table tbody').last('tr').append('<tr><td >2</td><td class="unit">8</td></tr>');
  
  total=0;
  $('.unit').each(function(){  total+=parseInt($(this).text()); });
  
  $('.total').text(total);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1px">
 <thead>
 <tr>
   <th>colum1</th>
   <th >colum2</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td >1</td>
    <td class="unit">6</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td >2</td>
    <td class="unit">8</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 
 <input type="button" value="new row" />
 <p class="total" ></p>
```